# How to refactor already simple ruby code

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I want to refactor this ruby code

```
class UtilService


  def summer_start
    ...
  end

  def summer_end
    ...
  end 

  def calc(date, charge, quantity, winter_rate, winter_service_charge, summer_rate)
    if date < summer_start || date > summer_end
      chargeamt = quantity * winter_rate + winter_service_charge
    else
      chargeamt = quantity * summer_rate
    end
    chargeamt
  end
end
```

Since charge isn't being used I know I can get rid of that but other than getting rid of that one parameter I can't think of what else I can actually do.

I was also thinking of breaking up 'calc' into different methods

```
class UtilService
  def summer_start
  end

  def summer_end
  end

  def calc_summer_rate(date, quantity, summer_rate)
    if date > summer_start || date < summer_end
      chargeamt = quantity * summer_rate
    end
    chargeamt
  end

  def calc_winter_rate(date, quantity, winter_rate, winter_service_charge)
    if date < summer_start || date > summer_end
      chargeamt = quantity * winter_rate + winter_service_charge
    end
    chargeamt
  end

end
```

But it doesn't seem like my refactoring makes much sense.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see big refactoring needed, maybe just moving the *is summer?* logic to another method and removing unnecesary `chargeamt` variable; something like this:

```
class UtilService
  def summer_start
  end

  def summer_end
  end

  def calc(date, quantity, winter_rate, winter_service_charge, summer_rate)
    if summer?(date)
      quantity * winter_rate + winter_service_charge
    else
      quantity * summer_rate
    end
  end

  private
  def summer?(date)
    date > summer_start || date < summer_end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't there be an issue with date being a local var?

Comment: @user2914144 Yes, thanks for the catch. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Sweet thanks. I'm testing this just to see if it's all good and I'm getting an error that says "comparison of Fixnum with nil failed" any idea what the issue is?

Comment: But i think since you got rid of chargeamt, it's returning a boolean

Comment: @user2914144 No, ruby returns the last expression evaluated when no explicit return is provided; so it will either return the result of the expression in `if` or the one in `else`, both numbers. How are you testing your code?

Comment: Oh hm, I give summer_start and summer_end random vals and then I pass random vals to calc and I get False (I got an int value with the original code so not sure what is happening)

Comment: I think it might be returning False because of the val I'm passing is NOT summer but then it maybe fails regardless thanks a bunch for your help :)

Comment: @user2914144 It shouldn't return `false` in any case, so maybe there is some error in the way you are setting up the test. You can check the code in action [here](https://repl.it/JcDW).

Answer (score 3):

I would be inclined to write something like the following.

```
rates = { winter: { per_unit: 123, service_charge: 456 },
          summer: { per_unit: 135, service_charge: 0   } }

def calc(date, quantity, rates)
  rate = summer?(date) ? rates[:summer] : rates[:winter]
  quantity * rate[:per_unit] + rate[:service_charge]
end

def summer?(date)
  date.between?(summer_start, summer_end)
end
```

Comment: I like this approach, it feels more organized (and flexible with `rates`); just a couple of typos: `rates(:summer)` to `rates[:summer]` and `per_unit` to `rate[:per_unit]`.

Comment: @Gerry, thanks for both the compliment and corrections. My answers always seem to be riddled with errors when I can't or don't test. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯